# %SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Caches getting created when executing vb script

Tags: java, windows, vbscript, startmenu

I need to create some shortcuts in StartMenu Group on Windows 7 in this location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

I first create shortcuts on the desktop and then copy them to the location C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\. The shortcuts work properly from here but strange thing I see is that a folder structure is created from where I run my program, after I execute my script, the folder structure looks like this

```
%SystemDrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Caches
```

**I am executing the vbscript from my java program using**

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env); 
result = p.waitFor();
```

cmd here is `wscript.exe (path of temp file which is the vbscript)`
env is the arguments I pass to the vb script

My vbscript is as below

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshEnv = WshShell.Environment("Process")
startMenu = WshShell.SpecialFolders("AllUsersStartMenu")
shortcutPath=WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%shortcut_path%")
type=WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%type%")
mydir = "\Programs\" & type & "\"
program_dir = startMenu & mydir



Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fso.FolderExists(program_dir) = 0) Then
    execCommand = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C md """ & program_dir & ""
    Set execStatus = WshShell.Exec(execCommand)
    ' command md take a time, this can be fail for .Save
    If execStatus.Status = 0 Then
        WScript.Sleep 1000
    End If
End If


Set fs1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If (fs1.FolderExists(program_dir)) Then
    fs1.CopyFile shortcutPath,program_dir
End If
Set fs1 = Nothing
```

I don't have much of an idea why this is happening and it doesn't happen always. Any help to prevent this will be appreciated, I know I can delete that folder but I really don't want to do that unless that's the last resort.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is unrelated to VBScript. According to [this blog post](http://jeremymurray.org/doku.php/blog:20110804_directories_popping_up_named_systemdrive) the behavior you observed is probably caused by the environment variables `%SystemDrive%` and `%ProgramData%` being undefined in the context of your Java process.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, that seemed to be the issue as you pointed out. I had to pass the %SystemDrive% env variable explicitly in "env" in Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env) , now it seems to work. But no clue why you have to explicitly pass it , I don't use that variable directly in my script but I think the script references it somewhere.