# Pass environment to a child process

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I am running a script which launches a Java application. After execution the application creates a folder in the current working directory  `%systemdrive%/ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Caches\cversions.2.db`. I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116126/systemdrive-programdata-microsoft-windows-caches-getting-created-when-executin) question that the problem appears because of the variable `%SystemDrive%` being undefined in the executed Java context.

 The application is executed with :
`system("java -jar application.jar");`

 How do I explicitelly pass all the environment to the executed application?

Comment: How do you start the application? Please show a minimal example of how you run it, and how you clean it up again.

Comment: I don't understand the question. As far as perl is concerned, there is only one set of environment variables; there is no distinction between "user" and "system". You can provide whatever environment variables you want. The default behavior is to inherit everything.

Comment: If the java program runs as a child of the Perl program, a whitelist of allowed environment variables together with a `local %ENV` and some cleanup should work fine. But we really have to get some more details.

Comment: @simbabque I need to update the whole question because I found that the problem doesn't come from those configuration files. The problem is that the variable `%systemdrive%` is not known in the executed Java context.

Comment: @melpomene updated, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the string `%systemdrive%\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Caches` to create the folder then it isn't going to work. Only the command shell will expand environment variables in a command, and Perl or Java will need to explicitly expand the value. In Perl you would use

```perl
$ENV{SYSTEMDRIVE} . '\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Caches'
```

In Java you want

```java
System.getenv("SYSTEMDRIVE") + . "\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Caches"
```

Comment: The application doesn't use it explicitlly/directly. I guess some subcomponent creates this folder ...